# How do I force R to keep time value when selecting date/time cell?

Tags: r

I have a column of date/time values and I'm selecting the top cell and bottom cell with this:

```
> time1 <- Angels.rolling$date.hour[1]
> time1
[1] "2014-02-17 UTC"
> time2 <- Angels.rolling$date.hour[(nrow(Angels.rolling))]
> time2
[1] "2018-02-14 01:00:00 UTC"
```

time1 should show as "2014-02-17 00:00:00 UTC" since that is the value of the top cell, but it seems to remove the time because it's midnight. The column was already formatted with lubridate's ymd_hms().

How do I pull the entire date and time value into my time1 variable without losing the data?

Comment: You should abandon the use of the term "cell" when referring to items inside dataframe or matrix columns. You should also review the information at `?print.POSIXct` although the answer to this question is actually on the `?format.POSIXct` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time is still in the object, it's just not printed by default. If you want the time to be printed you can use `format`.

```
format(Angels.rolling$date.hour[1], '%Y-%m-%d %T %Z')
```